# Does the Japanese medicinal tonic, Yomeishu, help with fatigue, poor circulation and gastrointestinal illnesses?

Tags: alternative-medicine, herbalism

Yomeishu is a medicinal tonic from Japan. According to this the [Yomeishu web-site](http://www.yomeishu.co.jp/english/about/feature/indications.html),

> Yomeishu improves the following symptoms:
>
> **1. Physical fatigue**
>
> For people with the trouble of physical fatigue such as feeling tiredness, continuation of fatigue, etc. Yomeishu, as a health tonic, relieves fatigue while strengthening physical power.
>
> **2. Chilliness of tip of fingers, hands, hips and legs**
>
> For people with severe chilliness of hands, feet and hips caused by air conditioners. Active medicinal ingredients contained in Yomeishu widely circulate throughout the body with blood circulation to regulate the functions of metabolism, and as a result, chilliness is improved.
>
> **3. Continuation of gastrointestinal trouble after meal**
>
> For people with weak digestive organs, gastrointestinal disorders or susceptible to weakened stomach and intestines. Drinking Yomeishu before meals will regulate gastrointestinal activities and strengthen them.
>
> **4 Recovery of physical strength during and after illness**
>
> For people requiring physical strength during and after illness, and people with delayed recovery of physical conditions after illness. Active ingredients of Yomeishu will regulate principal activities of the body and lead to an original healthy condition.
>
> **5 Poor appetite**
>
> For people with poor appetite, or incapable of eating despite of appetite. Drinking Yomeishu before meals activates gastrointestinal workings due to the active ingredients and one is capable of recovering to normal appetite.
>
> **6 Susceptible to be tired or a weak body constitution**
>
> For people with a weak body or feeling a lack of strength. Yomeishu, as a health tonic with a moderate action, strengthens the body and steadily enhances physical power while alleviating physical fatigue.
>
> **7 Always look sick**
>
> For people with who are of little color due to the chilliness of the tips of the fingers caused by the accumulation of fatigue. The active ingredients of Yomeishu circulate throughout the body with the blood circulation, activate the whole body metabolism and improve the trouble of little color.

Comment: This does just seem like normal advertising prattle. 'accumulation of fatigue'? 'regulate principal activities'?

Comment: @Rory: I don't think we should be complacent about accepting nonsense from advertisers. In any case, this is worse than normal advertising prattle: "Being different from a therapeutic drug, Yomeishu does not exert its efficacy on a part of the body." - elsewhere on the site.

Comment: I had a quick look at the research; there is some, but it seems to be published in Japanese, which is making it hard to evaluate it. There is the "Central Research Laboratories" owned by Yomeishu Seizo Co." which have published some papers. The direct conflicts of interest for such research makes it difficult to trust.

Comment: I note they recommend 3 doses per day of 20mL of a liqueur which is 14% alcohol - 8.4mL of alcohol is a little more than half a glass of wine. If people don't feel the chill in their fingers quite so much, I'm not that surprised!

Comment: @Oddthinking - I'm sure there are plenty of people who would gladly volunteer for such a study. FOR SCIENCE!!!!

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't. There is no evidence to support that.

The claims in the question are based on a more than 20 years old study which assessed subjective symptoms:

> We administered 20 ml of Yomeishu (YMS) twice a day before meals for 12 weeks to 50 post-operative patients in gynecology and then inquired into their subjective 20 symptoms (sense of fatigue, insomnia, headache and heavy headedness, appetite, stomach-ache, abdominal inflation, vertigo, lumbago, etc.) The YMS group showed a significant improvement on 14 items compared with the control group. On the whole, a great improvement was observed in the YMS group with serious subjective symptoms as well, and there were significant differences for **general condition, sense of fatigue, and coldness in extremities**.

***Source:*** Takabayashi T, Sasaki H, Shintaku Y, Sasamoto K, Ozawa N, Hamazaki Y, Yajima A. [*Effects of a medicinal herbal liqueur, "yomeishu", on post-operative gynecological patients.*](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2239815) Am J Chin Med. 1990;18(1-2):51-8.

Comment: How do you know this is the only source for the claims?